# tolower() is returning a number instead of a the lowercase form?

Tags: c++, tolower

I am writing a program that asks for input of letters and and sorts them the letter and occurrence based on input. I'm at the end of my code and I am trying to convert the uppercase letters to lowercase. I'm trying to do this:

```
cout << tolower(char('A'+i)) << " " << alphabets[i] <<endl;
```

But the `tolower()` outputs a number instead of the lowercase version of the letter? Like for example, input `"aaaa"` gives me :

> 97 4

and input `"bbbbb"` gives me:

> 98 5

But when I take out the `tolower`, input like `"aaa"` will be:

> A 3

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: `tolower` returns `int`. Cast it to a `char` if you want to print the character.

Comment: "so I don't wanna post the whole code incase someone tries to copy it" -> but copying our answers is ok then? Seriously: Read [`man 3 tolower`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower)

Comment: Giving ascii value of character. You can convert it again to char using char mychar = intvalueReturned

Comment: One other minor concern in your code - beyond your question - is that `'A'+i` does not necessarily produce an uppercase alphabetic character.   For ASCII and related character sets, it does.   Other character sets do exist for which it does not.   There is no guarantee that letters (whether uppercase or lowercase) are a contiguous set of values - there can be other characters between `'A'` and `'Z'`.

Answer (score 5):

[`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) is an ancient function inherited from 1970's-era C, before function signatures reliably existed and before people really cared about different integer types for expressions.

So, it ignores types and returns a character in an `int`. Three alternatives:

1. Cast: `static_cast< char >( std::tolower( 'A' + i ) )`.
2. Use a variable: `char lower = std::tolower( 'A' + i );`
3. Use a [newer overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower): `std::tolower( 'A', std::locale() )`.

Comment: Wouldn't the cast to char risk singed integer overflow?

Comment: @juanchopanza If the function weren't defined to return a value within the range of `char`, it would be UB.

Comment: @Potatoswatter No, that conversion would be implementation-defined. Not UB.

Comment: @T.C. Fair nuff. It would be overflow, but it can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

[`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) both accepts and returns an int, and `std::cout` cannot know that the `int` returned represents a `char` value. You can fix this by converting to `char`:

```
cout << static_cast<unsigned char>(tolower(char('A'+i))) 
     << " " << alphabets[i] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple typecasting would solve this issue. For example:

```
char letter = 'J';
cout << char(tolower(letter)) << endl;
```